Ubuntu 23.10, Raspberry Pi 5 - How to add an RTC?
While previous RPi generations how no on-board real-time clock, the RPi 5 does include one. However, it has no battery backup, so if the R Pi looses power, time is lost. I need an RTC with a battery backup. I developed a HAT that includes a PCF85063AT RTC module and battery. Now, I am trying to figure out how to get Ubuntu to use of it.
The RTC module does show up correctly using i2cdetect with address 0x68.
I tried following this guide: https://dev.to/dev_neil_a/setup-an-rtc-module-with-a-raspberry-pi-4-and-ubuntu-server-2004-8e6#configure-the-rtc-module-in-ubuntu, but it is outdated, and following the steps haven't worked for me.
Here is my current script:
#!/bin/bash
set -e # Exit immediately if a command exits with a non-zero status
# Steps modified from https://dev.to/dev_neil_a/setup-an-rtc-module-with-a-raspberry-pi-4-and-ubuntu-server-2004-8e6#configure-the-rtc-module-in-ubuntu
# Install utilities that include hwclock
apt install util-linux-extra -y
# Register the RTC module
echo pcf85063 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device
# Disable linesi n /lib/udev/hwclock-set
if ! grep --quiet "# if [ -e /run/systemd/system ] ; then" /lib/udev/hwclock-set; then
cp /lib/udev/hwclock-set /lib/udev/hwclock-set.original
sed -i '/if \[ -e \/run\/systemd\/system \] ; then/,/fi/s/^/# /' /lib/udev/hwclock-set
sed -i 's|/sbin/hwclock --rtc=\$dev --systz --badyear|# /sbin/hwclock --rtc=$dev --systz --badyear|' /lib/udev/hwclock-set
sed -i 's|/sbin/hwclock --rtc=\$dev --hctosys|# &|' /lib/udev/hwclock-set
fi
# Ensures the RTC module is correctly loaded at boot time
if ! grep --quiet "dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf85063,addr=0x68" /boot/firmware/config.txt; then
echo dtoverlay=i2c-rtc,pcf85063,addr=0x68 >> /boot/firmware/config.txt
fi
# Ensures the RTC module is correctly loaded at boot time
if ! grep --quiet "rtc-pcf85063" /etc/modules; then
echo rtc-pcf85063 >> /etc/modules
fi

After running these commands and rebooting, here is what I see:
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# cat /proc/modules | grep rtc
rtc_pcf85063 24576 0 - Live 0xffffa000717a4000
regmap_i2c 12288 1 rtc_pcf85063, Live 0xffffa0007179a000
rtc_rpi 12288 1 - Live 0xffffa000710c4000
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# lsmod | grep rtc
rtc_pcf85063 24576 0
regmap_i2c 12288 1 rtc_pcf85063
rtc_rpi 12288 1
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# ll /dev/rt*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Apr 4 18:59 /dev/rtc -> rtc0
crw------- 1 root root 251, 0 Apr 4 18:59 /dev/rtc0
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc0 --show
1970-01-01 01:20:09.284950+00:00
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# date
Thu Apr 4 19:53:41 UTC 2024
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 --show
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
hwclock: Use the --verbose option to see the details of our search for an access method.
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 --show --verbose
hwclock from util-linux 2.39.1
System Time: 1712260435.095222
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# i2cdetect -y 1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 a b c d e f
00: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
10: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
20: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
30: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
40: -- -- 42 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
50: -- 51 -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --
60: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- -- 68 -- -- -- -- -- -- --
70: -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --

I think that /dev/rtc0 is the on-board RTC. Is my RTC not getting registered correctly?
i2cdetect still shows the address as 68 rather than UU. If I run echo pcf85063 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device again, then I get UU. It seems like this "new_device" is not persistent across reboot?
Any thoughts here would be appreciated. Thank you!
Edit:
dmesg after fresh reboot:
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# dmesg | grep -i rtc
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: coherent_pool=1M 8250.nr_uarts=1 pci=pcie_bus_safe snd_bcm2835.enable_compat_alsa=0 snd_bcm2835.enable_hdmi=1 bcm2708_fb.fbwidth=640 bcm2708_fb.fbheight=480 bcm2708_fb.fbdepth=16 bcm2708_fb.fbswap=1 smsc95xx.macaddr=D8:3A:DD:AB:BE:42 vc_mem.mem_base=0x3fc00000 vc_mem.mem_size=0x40000000  console=ttyAMA10,115200 multipath=off dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=LABEL=writable rootfstype=ext4 rootwait fixrtc
[    0.000000] Unknown kernel command line parameters "fixrtc multipath=off", will be passed to user space.
[    1.807444]     fixrtc
[    2.101483] rpi-rtc soc:rpi_rtc: registered as rtc0
[    2.148523] rpi-rtc soc:rpi_rtc: setting system clock to 1970-01-01T01:35:11 UTC (5711)

After running echo pcf85063 0x68 > /sys/class/i2c-adapter/i2c-1/new_device again, I get:
root@GATEWAY-0x0000001E:~# hwclock --rtc=/dev/rtc1 --show --verbose
hwclock from util-linux 2.39.1
System Time: 1712257289.018692
Using the rtc interface to the clock.
Assuming hardware clock is kept in UTC time.
Waiting for clock tick...
ioctl(4, RTC_UIE_ON, 0): Invalid argument
Waiting in loop for time from /dev/rtc1 to change
hwclock: ioctl(RTC_RD_NAME) to /dev/rtc1 to read the time failed: Invalid argument
...synchronization failed

And these additional lines in dmesg:
[  102.669335] rtc-pcf85063 1-0068: registered as rtc1
[  102.669362] i2c i2c-1: new_device: Instantiated device pcf85063 at 0x68

